# Powershell piped out-file -append adding additonal CRLF between lines

Tags: powershell

this is probably very simple but I've not been able to get this working. Using either of these two very 'simple' scripts:

`get-date >> C:\list3.txt`  OR

`(get-date).Date | Out-String -FilePath C:\list3.txt -Append`

produces a text file with **too many leading and trailing CRLF**

**CRLF**
April 25, 2020 00:00:00 CRLF
**CRLF**
**CRLF**
**CRLF**
April 25, 2020 00:00:00 CRLF
CRLF
CRLF
CRLF

Behaves this way in either Notepad or Notepad++

What do I need to fix to have only one CRLF per line
April 25, 2020 00:00:00 CRLF
April 25, 2020 00:00:00 CRLF

thanks in advance

Comment: Simply output strings not objects  `(get-date).Date.ToString() | Out-File -FilePath C:\_Temp\list3.txt -Append` ... and Out-String does not have a parameter -FilePath AFAIK.   Use `Out-File` instead! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use set-content or add-content.  It doesn't add extra formatting.  Plus out-file -append can mix encodings (utf8, utf16) in the same file.

```
get-date | Add-Content file
get-date | Add-Content file
get-date | Add-Content file
cat file

4/25/2020 4:57:22 PM
4/25/2020 4:57:24 PM
4/25/2020 4:57:24 PM
```